# PHP Access Object

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am new to Objects , and I've been playing with this little object. Now I would like to know how I can acess an specific element of it .

This is the object :

```
stdClass Object ( [responseHeader] => stdClass Object ( [status] => 0 [QTime] => 0 ) [response] => stdClass Object ( [numFound] => 1 [start] => 0 [docs] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [schoolname_s] => School of Art [schoolstate_s] => FL [schoolcity_s] => Miami [pk_id] => 111212 [schoolcountry_s] => United States [name_s] => Example ) ) ) )
```

I would like to print pk_id.

I have tried :

```
$phpArray->pk_id;
```

And this was the result:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$pk_id in
```

Comment: `$phpArray->response->docs[0]->pk_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't accessing the right variable. What you want is this:

```
$phpArray->response->docs[0]->pk_id
```